# Can Percy Jackson control the human body?

Tags: percy-jackson

Can Percy Jackson control the human body because of his power over water and the level of water in the body? On a related topic, what effect would that have on the brain?

Answer (score 6):

Poseidon was considered to be the god of the sea, the massive, dangerous, deep body of water; not the god of fluids. It is more of the concept of the ocean (although Percy does manage to use fresh water) as opposed to all liquids.

Comment: That may be true, but we all know Percy controlled poison in tartarus. Why should this be diffirent?

Comment: @DemigodsonofPoseidon That was Tartarus, Percy's own narration says he could only do it because Tartarus has different rules. In Battle of the Labyrinth it is confirmed he can't control dog saliva so I find it unlikely that he can control blood.

Comment: You know how a lot of characters have a really strong will and do that "somehow" thing that helps them fight simulations, poison, evil influences, ect.? Maybe that.